# How to launch macro in "Word Macro Enabled Template" when opened?

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros

How can I get a Macro to run as soon as the file is opened?

I want to "Prefill" it from an external data source (Excel). I know how to fill the document but would like the Macro to run automatically

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Document.Open` event. You need to place the `Document_Open()` sub in the `ThisDocument` class module of your file. [Example from MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821870.aspx)

```
Private Sub Document_Open() 
    MsgBox "This document is copyrighted." 
End Sub
```

or in your case something like

```
Private Sub Document_Open() 
    Call PreFillDoc
End Sub
```

It will only run if macros are already enabled though.

Comment: I can't use Call MacroName or something similar? I dont mind pasting the code there but I was trying to keep my code in the Modules section for organization

Comment: @softwareisfun sure you can, see my edit. The macro needs to be public or you need to specify the module.